# Accessing method in MainActivity from Thread-Object

Tags: java, android, multithreading

in my Android App, I have a MainActivity Class, which starts a Thread. This Thread does Stuff and displays it on the screen. (This part is working)

**From the Thread** I want to access a method that is in the MainActivity-Class. But it does not work... "Cannot resolve method"

Here is my Code...

**The Thread-Object:**

```
public class SensorProcessor implements Runnable {

    protected Context mContext;
    protected Activity mActivity;

    private volatile boolean running = true;
    //Tag for Logging
    private final String LOG_TAG = SensorProcessor.class.getSimpleName();

    public SensorProcessor(Context mContext, Activity mActivity){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }


    public void run() {

            while (running){

                try {                    

                    final String raw = getSensorValue();
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //WORKS
                            final TextView textfield_sensor_value;
                            textfield_sensor_value = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.text_sensor);
                            textfield_sensor_value.setText("Sensor Value: " + raw);
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, raw);


                            //DOES NOT WORK, WHY?
                            mActivity.myMethod(); //Cannot resolve method
                        }
                    });



                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //When an interrupt is called, we set running to false, so the thread can exit nicely
                    running = false;
                }
            }

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Sensor Thread finished");

    }
}
```

**The MainActivity Class, which is calling the Thread:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {


    public void myMethod(){
        //Do stuff...
    }

    //Start the Thread, when the button is clicked
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button_start) {
            runnable = new SensorProcessor(this.getApplicationContext(),this);
            thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it not work, with the mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() - Approach, and how is this done correctly?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast you `mActivity` with `MainActivity` like `((MainActivity)mActivity)`. But make sure you should not update UI from thread.

Comment: Thank You (and all the others) For your quick answer. What do you mean, that I should not update UI from thread?

Comment: Don't use view related code in your method "myMethod()". like displaying toast messages or updating textview value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Handler in order to interact between threads and ui-thread (your activity) So here's how I would do this.

```
    public class SensorProcessor implements Runnable {

        protected Context mContext;
        protected Handler handler;

        private volatile boolean running = true;
        //Tag for Logging
        private final String LOG_TAG = SensorProcessor.class.getSimpleName();

      // here I pass a handler instead of activity
        public SensorProcessor(Context mContext, Handler handler){ 
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.handler = handler;
        }

    // here is the key. Replace  mActivity.myMethod(); with the following
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(randomIntegerNumberWhatever);
    ...etc etc
```

Then make a custom Handler that does something like dat

```
public class MessageHandler extends Handler
{
    public interface IHandler
    {
        void myMethod();
    }

    private final IHandler activityHandler;

    public MessageHandler(IHandler listener)
    {
        activityHandler = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (msg.what == randomIntegerNumberWhatever)
        {
            activityHandler.myMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Then have your activity implement the MessageHandler.IHandler interface. It may seem complicated but it works trust me

Answer (score 0):

`myMethod()` does not exist in the base `Activity` class, so cast to (or supply a) `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` class does not contain a `myMethod()` function.
You need to change the data type to your specific activity which has this function:

```
protected MainActivity mActivity;

public SensorProcessor(Context mContext, MainActivity mActivity){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
}
```